# string returns xstring file location

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main{
    string h = "";
    h = ("" + 'a');
    cout << h;

    return 0;
}
```

Output: "nity\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring"
I am honestly clueless as to what to do. I've never had this happen before.

Note: I've found a way to avoid this by appending the char like this:

```
string g="";
g+='a';
```

Regardless, why is this?

Comment: *Regardless, why is this?* -- `h = ("" + 'a');` -- This looks totally weird to a C++ programmer, however may not look weird to a JavaScript (or similar language) programmer.  Did you get the idea to do this from something like JavaScript?  What you are actually doing with that line of code has nothing to do with strings, and everything to do with taking a pointer and pointing it to who-knows-where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`""` is a literal of type `const char[1]`, which is the identical as `const char*` in most regards. `'a'` is a literal of type `char`, which is really just an integer type. So if you do `"" + 'a'`, you will get a pointer to `'a'` (=97 in ASCII) characters after wherever the compiler decides to put the `""`. Which is then converted to an `std::string`.

In the working example, you convert the `""` literal to `std::string` first, then add a `char` to it. `std::string` overloads the `+` and `+=` operators, so it will produce a reasonable result.

Comment: *So if you do "" + 'a', you will get a pointer to 97* -- This is under the assumption that the collating sequence is ASCII.  If it's something else, a lower case `a` could have a different value.

Comment: Edited to be more correct :)